# Editing two different iframe min-height's on same page using css + html

Tags: html, css, iframe

I need help, im currently stuck on how to set different min-height's for two different iframe videos from Youtube that are on the same page.

Currently what seem's to work (but only for one or the other) is changing the min-height on ".cms-page iframe" and setting it to !important.

Here is how the css currently looks right now:

```
.cms-page iframe {
   min-height: 564px !important;
}
```

Above is for the larger iframe, I am looking to also have a min-height of 250px for the smaller iframe.

Kind regards,
Harry

Comment: It would be helpful for you to share all your HTML and CSS here, so we can take a look at how everything is interacting.

Comment: Here is the CSS (slightly messy as my website is slightly weird when it comes to html/css, some css is also assigned to the specific cms page im editing on):
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qgxWjX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your css, change `.cms-page iframe` to `.vcontainer iframe`.

Comment: Thank you! it worked, I used vcontainer for large iframe and cms-page for smaller iframe, you saved me from crying xD

Answer (score 0):

Give a different `id` to each `iframe` and use it to define each one the min-height.
I gave the first one the id of `iframe1` and the second `iframe2`. take a look

```
#iframe1{
  min-height:250px !important;
}

#iframe2{
  min-height:564px !important;
}
```

Working perfectly :)

```css
.container-full {
width:100%;
margin:0;
}
.cms-page {
margin: 0;
}
.breadcrumb {
display: none;
}
.row .row {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 0px;
}
.col {
padding: 0px;
}
.image_full{
   display:block;
  }

 .image_mobile{
  display:none;
 }

@media (max-width: 640px) and (min-width: 320px){
  .image_full{
   display:none;
  }

  .image_mobile{
   display:block;
  }
  
  .container--pad {
   padding-left: 0rem;
   padding-right: 0rem;
  }
}
.button2 {
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ec1c24;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
.button2:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #111111;
  border: 3px solid #111111;
}
.FullWidthImg {
   width: 100vw;
   position: relative;
   left: 50%;
   right: 50%;
   margin-left: -50vw;
   margin-right: -50vw;
}
.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.img-wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
}
.hcontainer {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.pcontainer {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.vcontainer {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.ccontainer {
padding-top: 80px;
padding-bottom: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
.img-wrapper .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 64%; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.img-wrapper h2 {
  margin: 0 0 .5em;
}
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
 padding: 10px;
}
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


#iframe1{
  min-height:250px !important;
}

#iframe2{
  min-height:564px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="vcontainer">
<p><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/l01s5oDySjM" frameborder="0" width="100%" id="iframe1" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>

<div class="ccontainer">
<div class="hcontainer"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/c4e779335ad94d19c242bf724/images/75b2051f-dc4d-4ca1-96f1-273d67b214fa.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="pcontainer">
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 50px; padding-bottom: 50px;">
<div class="column">
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 18px; color: #777777;">We all know that after a long day, it&rsquo;s tough to have energy for a good workout. With the help of 1UP Pre-Workout, you won&rsquo;t feel hesitant to go train and put in the hard work.</span></p>
</div>
<div class="column">
<p id="small"><iframe id="iframe2" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pKJgRkV2vI8" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't have to work around the iframe width/height with this code. Just set the width to the outer div.

```css
.embed-responsive {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.embed-responsive .embed-responsive-item,
.embed-responsive embed,
.embed-responsive iframe,
.embed-responsive object,
.embed-responsive video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
}

.embed-responsive-16by9 {
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div style="width:33%">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/iOHkyZ62jjQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" id="widget2"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div style="width:100%">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/iOHkyZ62jjQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" id="widget2"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```